# Bhaskara iniciante

Tags: c#

Quando eu compilo esse código, aparece: `a1 vale NaN(Não é um número)` e depois: `a2 vale NaN(Não é um número)`, segue o código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int c = 5;

    double delta;
    double a1;
    double a2;

    delta = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;
    a1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
    a2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);

    MessageBox.Show("a1 vale " + a1);
    MessageBox.Show("a2 vale " + a2);

}
```

Comment: Raiz de um número negativo não dá número real. Esse é o problema

Comment: você deve verificar o valor do delta antes de continuar. Se Δ = 0 , haverá apenas uma raiz
Se Δ < 0 , não terá raízes. 
Se Δ > 0 , terá duas raízes reais diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

Raiz de negativo é NAN

9 - 40 é -31, e esse é o valor de `delta`

Seguindo tua linha de raciocínio do código (que é mostrar mensagem com a resposta) tu poderias colocar o seguinte teste:

```
if (delta < 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("Essa função não possui zeros reais");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o resultado que buscado em delta é um numero negativo você pode programar sua função para também se adaptar e assim mostrar o resultado levando em conta os números complexos. O cálculo de uma raiz negativa é simples apenas deve-se multiplica-la por -1 e no final da operação acrescentar um "i" que sinalizara o numero complexo, sendo assim obtemos algo parecido com isso:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int c = 5;

    double delta;
    double a1;
    double a2;

    delta = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;

    if (delta < 0)
    {
    delta *=-1;
    a1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
    a2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);

    MessageBox.Show("utilizando-se da propriedade dos numeros complexo obtemos que:");
    MessageBox.Show("a1 vale " + a1+"i");
    MessageBox.Show("a2 vale " + a2+"i");
    }

    else
    {
    a1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
    a2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);

    MessageBox.Show("a1 vale " + a1);
    MessageBox.Show("a2 vale " + a2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Gostei do jeito como contornaste o problema da raiz. Talvez fosse ainda melhor usar o tipo complexo que a linguagem dispõe ficasse ainda melhor